# Create async WebPack CommonsChunk with entire npm modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to create one async commons chunk with `react-dnd` and the two `react-dnd` back ends, and a second with all remaining node utilities (anything in `node_modules`).

The code is below.  My `react-dnd` bundle **does** have those three `npm` utilities in it, but that's all it has.  It doesn't have the things that *those* utilities depend on, like `dnd-core`, etc. Those dependencies are in the catch-all bundle, `all-node`

What's the most straightforward way to achieve what I'm looking for?

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    filename: 'all-node.js',
    async: 'all-node',
    minChunks(module, count) {
        var context = module.context;
        return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
    },
}),

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    chunks: ['react-dnd'],
    filename: 'react-dnd.js',
    async: 'react-dnd',
    children: true,
    minChunks(module, count) {
        var context = module.context;
        var targets = ['react-dnd', 'react-dnd-html5-backend', 'react-dnd-touch-backend']
        return count > 1 || (context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0 && targets.find(t => new RegExp('\\\\' + t + '\\\\', 'i').test(context)));
    },
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize now this is a fundamentally bad idea.  npm modules' dependencies can be shared between one another, and so forcibly sticking, say, react-dnd's full dependency tree into one bundle, with, say, react-router's full tree in another, will result in duplication among the union of their trees.